# Get the most frequently occuring string values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset with NBA players by match and I want to know if there is a way to get the **mode** statistic equivalent that is generally used for continuous values, but to get the most frequently occurring string values?

```
    t1_start1           t1_start2          t1_start3       t1_start4    t1_start5   team1
0   Shaquille O'Neal    Kobe Bryant         Horace Grant    Ron Harper  Rick Fox    LAL
1   Shaquille O'Neal    Kobe Bryant         Horace Grant    Ron Harper  Rick Fox    LAL
2   Kobe Bryant         Shaquille O'Neal    Horace Grant    Ron Harper  Brian Shaw  LAL
3   Kobe Bryant         Shaquille O'Neal    Horace Grant    Brian Shaw  Ron Harper  LAL
4   Kobe Bryant         Shaquille O'Neal    Horace Grant    Ron Harper  Brian Shaw  LAL
5   LeBron James        Brandon Ingram      Kyle Kuzma      JaVale McGeeLonzo  Ball  LAL
```

Regardless of player starters' orders `(t1_start1 | t1_start2 | t1_start3 | ... )`, how would I get 5 top most used players in the past 3 rows grouped by column 'team1'?

Comment: have you tried anything? is this a pandas dataframe that you pasted here?

Comment: @JoranBeasley yes, part of it

Comment: The mode is the most frequent value. They already don't have to be continuous values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.unique()` with `return_counts=True` and `np.argsort()`:

```
players, starts = np.unique(df[['t1_start1','t1_start2','t1_start3','t1_start4','t1_start5']].values, return_counts=True)

players[np.argsort(-starts)][:5]
```

Returns:

```
['Horace Grant' 'Kobe Bryant' 'Ron Harper' "Shaquille O'Neal" 'Brian Shaw']
```

Comment: This is better :D

Answer (score 0):

```
flat_list = df.loc[[0:3]].values.flatten() # first 3 rows flattened to a 1d list
print(scipy.stats.mode(flat_list).mode) # the most common element in that list
```

if you want more than just one value you can use collections.Counter

```
most_common_5 = collection.Counter(flat_list).most_common(5)
```

Comment: This only gets top 1 frequently used values, not top 5